# MongoDB use position in sorted query result to compute field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose Model for users. Each user has a certain amount of points. I'd like to create a field that is the users rank where:

```
rank = user position sorted by rank / total users
```

Let's suppose the user model looks like this:

```
{
    'name': 'bob',
    'points': 15,
    'rank': 9/15,
}
```

(I realize that the fraction would really be a decimal when stored).

Is there a way that I can update all of these users by:

1) Sorting them by points

2) Get a user's index in this sorted list

3) Divide that index by the total number of items in the list

I'm not sure what kind of mongo operators are out there for finding a doc's position in query results and for finding the total size of the query results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a couple of queries and a bit of JavaScript. Expanding on the steps you outlined, what you need to do is:

1. Find all of the user documents, sort them by `points` in descending order and assign the results to a cursor. You might want to ensure that you have an index on this field to make this query run faster.
2. Get the count for the number of documents returned.
3. Keep track of the position of the document within the results using an index.
4. Iterate through the documents, calculating the `rank` using the count and the index, and updating the corresponding user's `rank` with the result of that calculation.

In the `mongo` shell, the code would look something like the following.

```js
var c = db.user.find().sort({ "points": -1 });
var count = c.count();
var i = 1;
while (c.hasNext()) {
    var rank = i / count;
    var user = c.next();
    db.user.update(
        { "_id": user._id },
        { "$set": { "rank": rank } }
    );
    i++;
}
```

So if you had the following three users in your collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af63cfb269d664de0b4e"),
    "name" : "bob",
    "points" : 15,
    "rank" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af7fcfb269d664de0b4f"),
    "name" : "arnold",
    "points" : 20,
    "rank" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af95cfb269d664de0b50"),
    "name" : "claus",
    "points" : 10,
    "rank" : 0
}
```

After the update their documents would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af63cfb269d664de0b4e"),
    "name" : "bob",
    "points" : 15,
    "rank" : 0.6666666666666666
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af7fcfb269d664de0b4f"),
    "name" : "arnold",
    "points" : 20,
    "rank" : 0.3333333333333333
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f0af95cfb269d664de0b50"),
    "name" : "claus",
    "points" : 10,
    "rank" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks cool! Is the update() atomic? The main reason I wanted to do this all in one mongo query was to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: All write operations in MongoDB are atomic at the document level. The only thing to note is that you are updating all the documents according to their rank at a given point in time. By the time you finish the update, the rank might have changed, but this is an issue you will run into.

Answer (score 2):

Using the previous answer is not a good idea. It requires recalculating `rank` after each update of `points` values.

**Mongo version 5.0+ introduced [$rank](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) aggregation**:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
   {
      $setWindowFields: {
         sortBy: { points: 1 },
         output: {
            rank: {
               $rank: {}
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

will output

```
{ "points": 140, "rank": 1 },
{ "points": 160, "rank": 2 },
{ "points": 170, "rank": 3 },
{ "points": 180, "rank": 4 },
{ "points": 220, "rank": 5 }
```